# Passing data to top-level React component

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS newb question. I'm sure this is obvious, but I can't find the place in the doc.

I have a React component, which is rendered like so:

```
React.render(
  <MyComponent data="{myVar}" />,
  document.getElementById("element")
);
```

When myVar changes, it doesn't appear to automatically call the `componentWillReceiveProps` method on MyComponent, which I assumed it would. That's fine, but how do explicitly tell the component to update? I gather setState() is done internally within the component.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found it: looks like `setProps` was added for this very purpose, e.g.

```
var myComponent = React.render(
   <MyComponent data={myVar} />,
   document.getElementById("element")
);

// ... later on ...

myComponent.setProps({ data: 'newData' });
```

Comment: It should be `data={myVar}` (no quotes).

Comment: Thanks, FakeRainBrigand - fixed up.

Comment: This is deprecated now. See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html